# Multiple Model and Table Schema Advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have 3 models...

> Post, Logo_Category and Logo

and 5 tables

> posts, logos, logo_categories, logos_posts and logos_categories_posts

A post can have any number of logos from any number of logo_categories. I have started down the line with HABTM but I think I may have chosen the wrong path in terms of my schema.

Anyone have any idea what is the best way of associating these models?

Cheers

**EDIT**

Sorry guys, I thought I had solved this issue but...

In line with what Paul suggested I have now changed my associations to the following.

*POST.erb*

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :logos
has_many :logo_categories, :through => :logos
```

LOGO.erb

```
  belongs_to :logo_category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
```

LOGO_CATEGORY.erb

```
has_many :logos
has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
```

and my tables are now...

> posts (id) , logos (id), logos_posts (id, logo_id, logo_category_id),
>   logo_categories (id)

My post _form loads fine and all of the logos and logo_categories are loaded with the correct values and checked/unchecked (when editing a post) correctly.

I can check a new logo or uncheck an existing one and that records fine. However, if I alter a logo_category I get the following error!

> Cannot modify association 'Post#logo_categories' because it goes
>   through more than one other association.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sketch up a class diagram. Find 1-to-1 or n-to-1 relationships to simplify your tables. First question I have is can one logo have more than one category?

Comment: Post can have many logos and logo_categories. Logo category has many logos. Logo can only have one category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your table:

```
[posts] 1--n [post_logos] n--1 [logo] n--1 [logo_category]
```

- Each post has one row in post table with a unique post_id
- Each logo
  has one row in logo table with a unique logo_id
- Each logo table row
  is linked to one logo_category row
- Each time a logo is associated
  with a post, a row is created in post_logos table. It has
  two foreign-key columns: post_id and logo_id.

In ruby, each Post object could have an array or list of logo objects. Each Logo object composes one Logo_Category object (has one Logo_Category member or variable) .

Comment: To clarify, you're suggesting that instead of having two completely separate tables (logos and logos_categories) and joining them using logos_categories_posts ... I should add a logo_category_id column to logos and then join them using logos_posts table (it will be logos_posts not posts_logos, right?)

Comment: Yes, the logos_categories_posts table is unnecessary. Because logos can have at most one category (but categories can be mapped to multiple logos), logos and categories should be associated using a foreign-key column in the logos table pointing to categories. (It doesn't matter what you name the logos_posts table).

Comment: Ideal. Thanks Paul. I tried to vote your post as (very) useful but my rep won't allow it! Thanks for your help. I will try it out ASAP.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you say - "[posts] 1--n [post_logos] n--1 [logo] n--1 [logo_category]". Which associations do, 1--n/n--1, translate to?

Comment: Basically, [A] n--1 [B] means B can be related to many A's, and vice versa for 1--n.  I think in some types of diagrams the n's and 1's may be reversed. Take a look at wikipedia's page on ER diagrams (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Er_diagram) for more info.